# Git - How to color a failed push

Tags: git

When a git push fails due to something like:

```
! [rejected]        develop -> develop (fetch first)
```

How would one color this type of error in the terminal?

Comment: Note: with Git 2.18 (Q2 2.18), you will have a color associated with this type of error in the terminal! See [my updated answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27197704/6309)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't color it with Git itself.
That error message is done on stderr.

Independently of Git, you can try and [apply color to stderr](https://serverfault.com/q/59262/783).

You have other options at "[How to colorify git errors, warnings and fatal messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14417731/6309)".
For instance, the project [`sickill/stderred`](https://github.com/sickill/stderred) is illustrated [in this article](http://sysmagazine.com/posts/207768/):

[image: http://hsto.org/getpro/habr/post_images/90e/bfe/8c7/90ebfe8c7452f3f2fb47260720ca78b6.png]

---

Note: with Git 2.18 (Q2 2018, 4 years later), that kind of error message on push will actually be colored!
See more at "[How to colorify git errors, warnings and fatal messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50440338/6309)".