# Does git pull/push support colors

Tags: git, bash

When i do a `git status` I get nice pretty colors on my display.

However git `push/pull/fetch` are just monochrome boring

I have : `git config color.ui always` set to on but it appears I don't get no colors for anything other than status.

Am I missing something?

I'd love to see a red message pop out if something was rejected.  Perhaps there is a way to wrap the git output in a color processor?

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration doesn't seem to talk about push/pull

i.e. I'd love to color my error line in red here:

```
To ssh://<REPO ADDRESS>
 ! [rejected]        develop -> develop (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://<REPO ADDRESS>'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I guess it might be possible to wrap it somehow in a script that if a line has `error:` it will make it red?  I know there is a color maven "thing" out there that does something to maven output.

Answer (score 5):

Looking for string *color* in push.h, pull.h or fetch.h, reveal that they don't use coloring functions of git.

But if you want to color git errors, you could use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14417731/1092151) from another stack overflow question: [How to colorify git errors, warnings and fatal messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414696/how-to-colorify-git-errors-warnings-and-fatal-messages)