# How to make git output show red or orange color when it contains the word "error", "warning", or "Aborting"?

Tags: bash, git, zsh

Is there a way to make `git`'s output to show colors for the important words such as "error", "warning", or "aborting"? (case insensitive).

There are times when I do a `git pull` and the output is several lines, and I don't usually read all of them, but down at the last line, there is a word "Aborting", which escaped my attention.

So is there a way to show words in colors that indicate some error conditions?  By the way `git config --global color.ui true` or `git config --global color.ui auto` won't do it, as I intentionally created some merge conflict on the Mac and on Ubuntu and no color output came out. (I am using the latest git, on Mac, git 2.6.4, and on Ubuntu, git 2.7.2).

Comment: I found a solution good enough for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35904417/508194

Comment: This is a general shell solution rather than git specifically: https://superuser.com/questions/542074/how-can-i-customize-the-color-of-error-messages-in-bash#answer-542917

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the issue *might* be with terminal color display in general, in which case there are many other posts that provide suggestions such as:

1. Check your terminal emulator's settings - research based on the specific emulator you're using - eg. "issue with iTerm colors" or "issue with Gnome terminal colors"
2. Confirm settings for your shell, eg:

   ```
   # Set CLICOLOR if you want Ansi Colors in iTerm2 
   export CLICOLOR=1

   # Set colors to match iTerm2 Terminal Colors
   export TERM=xterm-256color
   ```