# Title not accepted: How to set the color for error messages

Tags: git

My current `git push` output is as follows:

[image]

The error message is hardly visible. The above is despite the following setting:

```
[color "interactive"]
  error = red bold
```

What should be the setting for error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git config color.push.error "red bold"
```

Answer (score 2):

That seems to be a remote sideband output, which means you need:

- [Git 2.19+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50440338/6309)
- `git config color.remote.error "red bold"`
- `git config color.remote always`

That would color what the *remote* is producing.

But in your case, if the error message is *not* produced by the remote, then the color would be managed by [`color.interactive.<slot>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-colorinteractiveltslotgt):

```
git config color.interactive.error "red bold"
```

(and an error "`failed to push to remote...`" is likely to be produced by your local Git instance, not by a remote sideband output)

Or, as the OP comments: [`color.push.error`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-colorpusherror):

```
git config color.push.error "red bold"
```

In both cases, this is a *local* color setting, not a remote one.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I set `color.remote.error`, `hint` and `warning` to "red bold" but `git push` still comes out dull red.

Comment: @OldGeezer What version of Git are you using?

Comment: git version 2.21.0.windows.1

Comment: @OldGeezer Can you try with `color.remote always` and `color.remote.error "red bold"`, as in https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf1a11f0a100b080a25233980c14b5ae8f3a7d2d#diff-5baff4b2e097c317e9945480560bcdd0R68?

Comment: @OldGeezer In other words, setting the color alone is not enough, setting `color.remote=always` might be required.

Comment: Alas, still no joy. My config file now contains [color]\n ui=auto\n remote=always\n[color "remote"]\n error = red bold

Comment: @OldGeezer Strange (https://github.com/git/git/blob/1f672904508c9c4e722efaf6bb8696b2e7b9d8e0/t/t5409-colorize-remote-messages.sh#L33-L40) Unless the color you see is already bold red... Can you try with any other color, just for testing?

Comment: I changed all the remote colors to cyan just to test, but it remains dull red. So it looks like it is taking colors from somewhere else. I reproduce my config file contents in the question. I am not sure if there are any syntax errors in there. I also assume there is no need to "reboot" git after making config changes, ie they should take effect on the next use of a git command.

Comment: @OldGeezer I confirm: no need to reboot.

Comment: @OldGeezer All I can think of  is that the error is not one produced by remote, but by the local Git. That color would *not* be managed by `color.remote.error`

Comment: @OldGeezer Try instead https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-colorinteractiveltslotgt: `color.interactive.error`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I found the answer: `color.push.error`  Thanks for your help and guiding me to it.

Comment: @OldGeezer Great! i have updated the answer accordingly.